# Conditional Typeorm QueryBuilder that updates in list of tuples

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to perform a conditional UPDATE query based on a 2D array that should look like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET head = 0 WHERE head = 1 AND (val1, val2) IN (('?', '?'), ('?', '?'));
```

This is what I got so far but it seems to generate wrong SQL query:

```
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .update(Entity)
        .set({ head: false })
        .where('is_head = 1 AND (val1, val2) IN (:...ids)', { ids: [[5,6], [7, 9]] })
```

Couldn't really find something helpful in the docs, is this actually possible with the mysql2 driver?

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, you can use a loop to generate the WHERE expression, like...

```
interface TupleQuery {
  tupleExpressions: string[];
  parameters: { [parameter: string]: unknown[] };
}

const ids: [number, number][] = [[5, 6], [7, 9]];
const initialValue: TupleQuery = { tupleExpressions: [], parameters: {} };
const { tupleExpressions, parameters } = ids.reduce((result, currentTuple, index) => ({
  tupleExpressions: result.tupleExpressions.concat([`(:...ids-${index})`]),
  parameters: { ...result.parameters, [`ids-${index}`]: currentTuple },
}), initialValue);

// ...afterwards
.where(`is_head = 1 AND (val1, val2) IN (${tupleExpressions.join(', ')})`, parameters)
```